# JComboBox doesn't get my values

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a problem with my JComboBox.

**description:**
I create a new file by writing the name of my file in a Textfield. By clicking on a button I create a file with this value and add this into my JComboBox, but I only see the Object value, for example "[Ljava.io.FIle;@1b1428d" and that's the problem. The user doesn't even know what this value means so I need my filename. I searched for a long time and Yes the `toString()` doesn't work :D

My Code looks like this: `JComboBox TxtDoc = new JComboBox(create());`

```
public File[] create(){
    FileSystemView SYSTEM = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
    String user = System.getProperty("user.home")+"\\notes";
    File userdir = new File(user);
    File[] fileList = SYSTEM.getFiles(userdir, true);
    return fileList;


}
newTxt.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event){
            new Documents().createTxtDoc(); // <-- this just open a new frame with my textfield and a button.
            TxtDoc.addItem(create());



        }
    });
```

thank you for your help
regards Blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iterate over it:

```
    for (File f : fileList) {
      TxtDoc.addItem(f);
    }
```

Comment: yeah I tried this too, but I believe that I have the problem that my FileSystemview  dont get the update (new file) 
but Iam glad for your response

Comment: that was nonsense I found my logic failure your right you helped me a lot thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're add an array `File`s as a single element of the combobox (that's what [`addItem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#addItem(E)) does, adds A (single) item)

There's a few ways you might be able to do this, one might be to simply reset the combo box's model...

```
TxtDoc.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(create());
```

This has the the nice side effect of removing all the previous elements first

Having said that, you might not like the results...

You may want to consider providing a custom cell render to render just the name of the file.  See [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) and [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for more details

Comment: I thought that I just have to update my Filesystemview so I will get my new files. I will try it with the ComboboxModel. Thank you for your response.